# How to not count negative input

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

is there a way to keep the counter going without counting the negatives and only to stop when the input is zero?

```
count = 0
total = 0
n = input()
while n != '0':
    count = count + 1
    total = total + int(n) ** 2
    n = input()
print(total)
```

Here is an example of execution result.

Input: `-1 10 8 4 2 0`
Output: `184`

Comment: What do you mean by "eject"? Do you want to keep asking for a number until it's >= 0?

Comment: Yes even if a negative number is an input, to keep going until I type zero

Comment: Eject has no meaning in this context. Please be precise on what you want to achieve. If possible, provide an example of the expected results.

Comment: Input: -1
10
8
4
2
0
Output:
184

Comment: @Lorin Please put the contents of your comment ( with the sample input and output ) in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your Input to an integer (number) and check if it's larger than zero:

```
count = 0
total = 0

num = int(input())

while number != 0:
    if number < 0:
        continue
    count += 1
    total = total + num**2
    num = int(input())
print(total)
```

The difference between pass, continue, break and return are:

- pass = ignore me an just go on, usefull when you create a function that has no purpose yet
- continue = ignore everything else in the loop and start a new loop
- break = break the loop
- return = end of a function - a return statement can be used to give an output to a function but also as a way to break out of the function like the break statement does in loops.

Comment: I see, but now the program stops immediately when a negative number is an input, is there a way to keep the counter going without counting the negatives and only to stop when the input is zero?

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you want only number to enter the `loop` you can use `isnumeric()` built in function to check that.
2. You need `if() : break` here.

```
num = input()
...
while(isnumeric(num)):
  ...
  if(num == "0"):
     break;
```

Answer (score 0):

The response you wait for is:

- ignore negative number
- count positive numbers
- stop when input is `0`

```py
count = 0
total = 0

n = int(input())

while (n != 0): 
    count += 1
    if (n > 0): 
        total = total + n**2
    num = int(input())

print(total)
```

Your code was already OK except that you did not cast the number `n` into `int` and you did not test `n` to take away negative values.

**Execution:**
When you enter `-1 10 8 4 2 0`, it should show `184`

Comment: I'm trying your suggestion but the counter won't stop when I input zero